# How to change the iVar of another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sdk

This is the code. It is pretty straight forward. I made two classes one is returning the error and hydrate the iVar of another class (TheView) and show it to the User. however I cant figure it out why the View return Null at all time. Thanks is advance guys.

```
     @interface AccountControllerModel : NSObject {
            NSString *anError;
        }
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *anError;

AccountControllerModel.m
    @synthesize anError;

    - (void)uploadFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{

RegistrationViewController *regoVC = [[RegistrationViewController alloc] init];
[regoVC manageTheError:@"THIS IS AN ERROR"];
[regoVC release]; regoVC = nil;
    }
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
    @interface RegistrationViewController : UIViewController {
        NSMutableString *test;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableString *test;

@synthesize test;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
  test = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
-(void)manageTheError:(NSString *)theError{
self.test = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theError];
resultOfRegistration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.test];
NSLog(@"test is %@",self.resultOfRegistration.text); //It comes back Null
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and title to actually ask a question. Instead of posting copypasta and expecting people to guess what your question is, point to the code where you are experiencing problems that relate to your question. This will help us help you.

Comment: Sorry Alex, Fixed it with the proper description.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right, some clarification on what's not working would help but by looking through I may have found your error. [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Blah" object:self], you have object set to nil which could be your issue with the notification.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

`@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableString *test;`

Two things here, one, exposing a NSMutable* object in a property is never a good idea, two you should 'copy' value objects, especially because this is how you're treating it in your code. Make this `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *test;`

`regoVC.test = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.anError];`

You're assigning an autoreleased object to an assign property, this is a leak, the change above will fix that.

`NSLog(@"test is %@",test); // It is perfect as you expect`

`test` isn't in scope here, but I'd assume that was supposed to be `regoVC.test`, these other changes should remedy the situation.